# Pandas Dataframe, getting average value for each monday 1 Am

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, average

my DataFrame looks like this:

```
index                   value
2016-03-21 00:00:00     0.613014
2016-03-21 01:00:00     0.596383
2016-03-21 02:00:00     0.623570
2016-03-21 03:00:00     0.663350
2016-03-21 04:00:00     0.677817
2016-03-21 05:00:00     0.727116
2016-03-21 06:00:00     0.920279
2016-03-21 07:00:00     1.205863
2016-03-21 08:00:00     0.880946
2016-03-21 09:00:00     0.186947
2016-03-21 10:00:00     -0.563276
2016-03-21 11:00:00     -1.249595
2016-03-21 12:00:00     -1.596035
2016-03-21 13:00:00     -1.886954
2016-03-21 14:00:00     -1.912325
2016-03-21 15:00:00     -1.750623
...     
2016-06-20 23:00:00     2.125791
```

I am trying to get the average for each monday at 1 am in the dataframe. In the end I want to have an output that represents the 'average week' of the dataframe, so I can visualize the course of the week.

I hope I could express myself clearly.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to interpret your question, so here are two answers (to different questions)

**to get the mean of all values that occur on a monday at 1:00 am (output will be a single scalar)**:

```
# Make sure the index is a pd.datetime object
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# find all rows which occur on a monday and at 01:00:00, and take the mean
monday_means = (df.loc[(df.index.weekday_name == 'Monday') &
                       (df.index.time == pd.to_datetime('01:00:00').time())]
                .mean()
                .to_frame('Monday 1 Am'))
```

**to get the mean of the previous week, with the week starting on monday at 1:00 am (output will be a series)**:

```
# Make sure the index is a pd.datetime object
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# Create a column for week number, which counts consecutively every monday at 1:00:00
df['week_number'] = ((df.index.weekday_name == 'Monday') &
                     (df.index.time == pd.to_datetime('01:00:00').time())
                     .cumsum())


# Groupby week number and get the mean
df.groupby('week_number').mean()
```

Or, more simply (but less flexible, it will start the week on monday at midnight, rather than 1 am):

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes this is what im looking for, but the code gives me an error 'NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined'. If i use pd.dateime, it throws me this error. TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Comment: yes the first answers works perfectly thanks!!! Is there a way to label the x-axis correctly? Like 'Monday 1 Am' or did i lose this information on the way