# Pandas average values for the same hour for each day

Tags: python, pandas

The post [Pandas Dataframe, getting average value for each monday 1 Am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806166/pandas-dataframe-getting-average-value-for-each-monday-1-am) described a similar problem as what I have right now, so I borrowed their dataframe. However, mine is a little bit harder and that solution didn't really work for me.

```
time                    value
2016-03-21 00:00:00     0.613014
2016-03-21 01:00:00     0.596383
2016-03-21 02:00:00     0.623570
2016-03-21 03:00:00     0.663350
2016-03-21 04:00:00     0.677817
2016-03-21 05:00:00     0.727116
2016-03-21 06:00:00     0.920279
2016-03-21 07:00:00     1.205863
2016-03-21 08:00:00     0.880946
2016-03-21 09:00:00     0.186947
2016-03-21 10:00:00     -0.563276
2016-03-21 11:00:00     -1.249595
2016-03-21 12:00:00     -1.596035
2016-03-21 13:00:00     -1.886954
2016-03-21 14:00:00     -1.912325
2016-03-21 15:00:00     -1.750623
...     
2016-06-20 23:00:00     2.125791
```

What I need to do is to get average value for each day at a specific time. Say, I have to get the average for every day at 1AM, and then 2AM, and then 3AM.
I would like to do this in a groupby way which might make the rolling avg I have do after that easier, but every method counts, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you need average value for every hour? What do you mean by specific time? Provide an example output for what you need.

Comment: I need a column which contains the average of value on 1AM, and on 2AM, and 3AM, etc., for every day from 2016-03-01 to 2016-06-20. The same hour on different days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary column that holds hours and group on that, eg:
`df['hour'] = df['time'].dt.hour`
and then
`hour_avg = df.groupby(['hour']).mean()`
note this approach aggregates hours over all years, months and days.

Comment: That's awesome! It answers my question, however I have one more question. The output of it is a series, while I want it to be a dataframe. I've tried ```to_frame``` but it doesn't really work. No error, it runs, just the type is still series. Any idea how to solve that, or just output the result as a dataframe ?

Comment: Without testing it, I believe you should be able to add it to an existing dataframe as a column

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the hours in a separate column and [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by it:

```
df['hour'] = df.time.dt.hour
result_df = df.groupby(['hour']).mean()
```